# ReactiveCocoa binding "networkActivityIndicator" Crushes

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have this code:

```
 RAC(self.viewModel , password) = self.signupCell.passwordTextField.rac_textSignal;
    RAC(self.viewModel , userName) = self.signupCell.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal;
    RAC([UIApplication sharedApplication], networkActivityIndicatorVisible) = self.viewModel.executeRegister.executing;
```

At my LogIn page. 
At first is runs perfect, But it user Logout and gets to the register page once again, the app crushes at the line:

```
 RAC([UIApplication sharedApplication], networkActivityIndicatorVisible) = self.viewModel.executeRegister.executing;
```

With Error:

**'Signal  name:  is already bound to key path "networkActivityIndicatorVisible" on object , adding signal  name:  is undefined behavior'**

I'm guessing it has something to do with subscribing to UIApplication events. But I'm not sure what else can i do beside sending subscriber completed as so:

```
 [subscriber sendCompleted]
```

Any one had the same problem?

thanks.

**EDIT**

With the help of @erikprice and @powerj1984 I found a solution:

```
RAC([UIApplication sharedApplication], networkActivityIndicatorVisible) = [self.viewModel.executeRegister.executing takeUntilBlock:^BOOL(id x) {
    return _viewShowing;
}];
```

The "_viewShowing" veritable is setted to YES on ViewWillAppear, And to NO on ViewWillDisapear.
This is not the best coding.. So if anyone has a better option i would be happy to use it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Try adding a takeUntil and do so until a signal sends @YES when the user leaves the login screen?

Comment: Thank you for the response, I can not seem to get it to "doUntil" the dealloc method gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message means that you're trying to call `RAC(UIApplication.sharedApplication, networkActivityIndicatorVisible)` more than once. Make sure you only make that call on that specific property of that specific object one time, ever. (Or at least until such time as you dispose of the subscription, as @powerj1984 suggests.)

Comment: Thanks you for your response, Could you show me an example or reference to how to do so please? I'm trying to "doUntil" the dealloc method gets called, But not sure how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: This is something that is really specific to how you wrote your code. My suggestion is that you launch your app in the debugger, and put a breakpoint on the line where you call `RAC()`. When it gets called a second time on the same object, look at the call stack to see how you got to that point, and then make whatever changes in your code are necessary to stop calling it twice on the same object and property combination.